# Ionic 1 public api protection to consume only by android smartphones

Tags: ionic-framework

I build an ionic app using version 1 some year ago, the app is public no authentication is required.

How can i enable api consume only from the android smartphone ?

If someone decompile the apk they can see the api and consume data from the api 
How can i prevent this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day, there isn't much you can do to completely prevent someone from accessing or scraping data via your public API.

However, here are some ideas that can help mitigate it:

**API Key**

Store an API Key in your app, and validate the key on the server side before processing the request. This suggestion isn't too helpful if they decompile your app, but at least it's a start in preventing the API from being exposed by just using the app (especially if you make all your HTTP requests over SSL).

**IP Address Logging**

Setup some code within your mobile app that logs the IP address of the user. Then, when a call is made to your public API - it compares the IP address from the request with the list of IP addresses that have been logged from the mobile app. You can even use timestamps to limit the time frame in which the API will be accessible.

**Rate Limits/Usage Quotas**

You can put some general rate-limits on your API. Only allow a certain number of requests within a specified time frame from any given IP address, user, device ID, etc.

Hope this helps. I would love to hear more thoughts from other people in the community as well!

Comment: yes this is really a big issue in case you need to expose an api without authentication